# Can someone explain what this type of pattern means in the residuals vs fitted plot?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

Any input would be appreciated

[image: plot from r]

Comment: Would you please add a scatterplot of the data used for the regression?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like manufactured (I.e simulated with minimal random noise component) data with multiple individuals with exactly linear decreases over time of some measurement.